# Word meaning "to make more accurate"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm looking for a single-word verb that means "to make more accurate".

The OED lists a word that might work, but the context is sort of restricted to an (in my opinion unfairly) small situation set. It lists the word *accurize*, which is fairly new (its first recorded use by the OED is from 1955), is originally & chiefly a US term, and means, "To adjust or modify (a firearm or (occas.) other device) in order to improve accuracy."

I can't find any other word that means the desired definition.

Comment: ***Tune or refine*** might fit, but what is the context you are referring to?

Comment: There is a word in your definition of accurize that would apply.  "The gun's aim was improved".

Comment: Though existing usage might have a limited context, *accurize* has the advantage of being immediately understandable.  At worst, it's no worse than marketer-speak.

Comment: Would have to agree with what others have said,  this is very much going to depend on the context.  "Clarify" is another word that comes to mind.

Comment: One can *tighten* an estimate.

Comment: Instead of saying, “we need to *accurize* this data.” we say, “we need to improve the accuracy of this data.”

Comment: No specific context. Just any context. Just looking for a word that means "to make more accurate". That's it.

Comment: @AlexanderDunlap: Good suggestion. I didn't think of that one.

Comment: @Jim: That wouldn't work because I need a single-word verb. That more or less requires several words. Thanks, though.

Comment: @SarahofGaia- The point is we don't really have such a word.  We may have a context-specific word but you haven't given us a specific context. For example in some contexts *calibrate* could be used to improve accuracy.  And a while a refinement does represent an improvement it is not always an improvement in accuracy.

Comment: Not every word requires a context. In fact, a lot of words don't. I'm not asking for a hugely complicated thing here. I just want to know a word that means, simply, "To make more accurate". Many words are like this; context just makes it more specific. I'm only referring to its base definition. 

If you don't know of such a word or if one doesn't exist, that's all I need to know. We don't need to make this more complicated than it is. I've noticed this happening **a lot** on SE in general. People here are *way* too over-specific oftentimes. To the point where they lose sight of the question.

Comment: A support tech just included the word 'accurated', used as a verb, in an email to me. I landed here as I tried to find out whether it's a real word, and what it means. ☺

Comment: If it exists, then certainly by definition it's a real word. A good question would be whether it's a commonly used word. That I cannot answer. Let me know if you find out, though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Answers from comments that I completely agree with:

> **Refine:** To improve in accuracy, delicacy, or excellence.

That's pretty much perfect.

> **Tighten:** To make tighter.

With this definition of 'tight', or a similar one:

> **Tight:** Well-rehearsed and accurate in execution.

We often say 'fine-tune' when talking about making something *even more* accurate, but 'tune' can be used as well, especially if the thing isn't very accurate to begin with.

> **Tune**: To make more precise, intense, or effective; to put into a proper state or disposition.

<sub>Definitions from Wiktionary.</sub>

Answer (score 17):

> **hone** *- to **perfect** or make more intense or effective*
>    [<sub><sup>(thefreedictionary.com)</sup></sub>](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hone)

From [Kiplinger's Personal Finance...](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Wyzkc3dFynYC&pg=PT62&dq=%22hone%20the%20numbers%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22hone%20the%20numbers%22&f=false)

> *To **hone** the numbers further, figure out how much income you would need to replace each month if you lost your job*

---

But in practice most people would probably use...

> **fine-tune** *- to make fine adjustments to (something) in order to obtain optimum performance*
>   [<sub><sup>(thefreedictionary.com)</sup></sub>](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fine-tune)

Comment: You've fine-tuned the format of your answer. How could you write the sources using small letters?

Comment: @Josh61: I could (and indeed ***can** and **did***) just enclose the relevant text within **<sub><sup>** and **</sub></sup>**. But that doesn't work in SO comments (which is just as well, or you wouldn't be able to make sense of this one! :)

Comment: Lol, **freaking beautiful**, @FumbleFingers. XD

Answer (score 6):

General purpose verbs you could use would be "correct" and "rectify".  But we need more context.  If you're referring to improving the accuracy of some type of tool or instrument, then 'calibrate' would be the best choice.

Comment: But does *calibrate* mean "to make more accurate"?

Comment: @WS2: Yes; an uncalibrated scale might read the actual weight of the object plus 5 pounds, After (correctly) calibrating the scale, it would then read the true weight.

Comment: @Hurkyl: An uncalibrated thermometer might not "read" anything at all (though you could safely assume that the higher up the tube the liquid goes, the hotter it is). So in at least *some* contexts, "calibration" doesn't necessarily mean *make [existing readings] **more** accurate* - it can just mean *make a measuring device **capable of indicating a "value"*** (whether "accurate" or not).

Comment: Calibration improves the accuracy of uncalibrated systems. Once calibrated, further calibration (ideally) has no effect on a system's accuracy.

Comment: "Calibration improves the accuracy of uncalibrated systems" - that may very well be true. Indeed many things may improve accuracy, such as people taking more care when they record measurements. But something that may have the effect of providing a more accurate result does not mean "to make more accurate" does it?

Comment: -1, 'correct' and 'rectify' both indicate that something was wrong and then fixed. It's a binary switch from incorrect to correct. That doesn't really work for taking something that already has some degree of accuracy, and improving that accuracy. Calibrate is similar. An uncalibrated something gives you garbage, once it's calibrated the results are correct. You don't calibrate it "more".

Comment: Un-calibrated doesn't necessarily give 'garbage', it can be the case, but it can also simply be slightly out of tolerance, therefore giving reliable readings that are just a little out of specification. Calibration isn't binary, there isnt just wrong or right, in some situations 'kind of right' is acceptable. The reading is wrong, but it's 'right enough', but could still benefit from calibration

Answer (score -1):

In some contexts *to specify* might work, although that doesn't inherently mean a less accurate version already existed.